# FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas all arguments of DataFrame.any and Series.any will be keyword-only

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here is the Python statement creating the problem:

```
nan_rows = df[df.isnull().any(1)]
```

And it gives the following warning:

```
FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas all arguments of DataFrame.any and Series.any will be keyword-only.
```

It is a warning from production environment. I am sorry that I am not able to share the complete code as it is fairly complex to fit into this question.

How can I understand what this warning is saying, and how should I update this line of code?

Comment: 1 is positional `axis=1` is with keyword

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from pandas 1.5, you get a `FutureWarning`.

You must specify `axis=1`:

```
nan_rows = df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
```

In a future version only keywords arguments will be accepted, omitting the keyword will raise an error.